# How can I fix LVM PV size after a botched encrypted partition shrinking

Tags: lvm, encryption, luks, parted

I apparently messed up today.

I have to resize an encrypted root partition to make room for a windows dual boot.
I followed instructions from [the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Resizing_LVM-on-LUKS#Shrink_LVM-on-LUKS) since it seemed to match my needs even though I am using debian. At some point I had to use `pvmove` because after shrinking the root partition, the free space was between my root and swap partition. I thought it all went well, but I apparently messed up my sector/bytes/stuff calculations at some point.
Right now the machine is booted from a live debian usb key and this is the output of what I think are the relevant shell commands.

```
user@debian:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0           7:0    0   2.3G  1 loop  /usr/lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.s
sda             8:0    0   3.6T  0 disk  
sdb             8:16   1 114.6G  0 disk  
sdc             8:32   1  28.9G  0 disk  
├─sdc1          8:33   1   2.5G  0 part  /usr/lib/live/mount/medium
└─sdc2          8:34   1   2.6M  0 part  
nvme0n1       259:0    0   3.6T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0   512M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p2   259:2    0   488M  0 part  
└─nvme0n1p3   259:3    0   3.5T  0 part  
  └─cryptdisk 253:0    0   3.5T  0 crypt  # this is where the "fun" happens
```

So, I managed to free 100G for windows, looks good so far. But...

```
user@debian:~$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 cryptdisk
Enter passphrase for /dev/nvme0n1p3: 
user@debian:~$ sudo vgchange -a y licorne-vg
  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/cryptdisk has size of 7602233344 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 7602235392 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG licorne-vg have changed sizes.
  device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (253:2) failed: Invalid argument
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "licorne-vg" now active
user@debian:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                    7:0    0   2.3G  1 loop  /usr/lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
sda                      8:0    0   3.6T  0 disk  
sdb                      8:16   1 114.6G  0 disk  
sdc                      8:32   1  28.9G  0 disk  
├─sdc1                   8:33   1   2.5G  0 part  /usr/lib/live/mount/medium
└─sdc2                   8:34   1   2.6M  0 part  
nvme0n1                259:0    0   3.6T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1            259:1    0   512M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p2            259:2    0   488M  0 part  
└─nvme0n1p3            259:3    0   3.5T  0 part  
  └─cryptdisk          253:0    0   3.5T  0 crypt 
    └─licorne--vg-root 253:1    0   3.5T  0 lvm
```

Panic intensifies... `253:2` was my encrypted swap partition which was part of this cryptdisk.

```
user@debian:~$ sudo pvdisplay /dev/mapper/cryptdisk
  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/cryptdisk has size of 7602233344 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 7602235392 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG licorne-vg have changed sizes.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/cryptdisk
  VG Name               licorne-vg
  PV Size               3.54 TiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              928007
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          928007
  PV UUID               x5fLwB-qnhM-qc4x-y28f-FdDM-pFGI-9I6SYh
   
user@debian:~$ sudo lvs
  WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/cryptdisk has size of 7602233344 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 7602235392 sectors. Was device resized?
  WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG licorne-vg have changed sizes.
  LV     VG         Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   licorne-vg -wi-a-----  <3.54t                                                    
  swap_1 licorne-vg -wi------- 976.00m

user@debian:~$ sudo dmesg | grep device-mapper
[   99.652244] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[   99.652317] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.43.0-ioctl (2020-10-01) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[  100.537014] device-mapper: table: 253:2: dm-0 too small for target: start=7600236544, len=1998848, dev_size=7602233344
[  100.537016] device-mapper: core: Cannot calculate initial queue limits
[  100.537027] device-mapper: ioctl: unable to set up device queue for new table.
[ 1451.395603] device-mapper: table: 253:2: dm-0 too small for target: start=7600236544, len=1998848, dev_size=7602233344
[ 1451.395605] device-mapper: core: Cannot calculate initial queue limits
[ 1451.395956] device-mapper: ioctl: unable to set up device queue for new table.
```

Is this LVM/LUKS setup in a recoverable state? I *think* that `licorne--vg-root` and only the swap partition suffered, which is OK, right? What steps should I follow here to fix things? Thanks for your help.

Comment: PV too small by 2048 sectors, lost the last PE, `parted /dev/nvme0n1 unit s print free` to verify there's no unpartitioned space, `lvs -o +seg_pe_ranges` to verify it's the swap LV - from the error message it should be so. If the missing space can't be reclaimed, you'd have to shrink swap by 1 PE (4M) and pvresize.

Comment: Parted output: https://dpaste.com/5YXXWHX56 and lvs output: https://dpaste.com/3A48496ZX
There is unpartioned space, as intended, since I did not begin installing win10 on it yet. I am a lost about whether I should and in which order I should use pvresize/lvresize/parted here :( Thanks for reading me.

Comment: Oh, in that case just make the partition larger by at least 2048s. In parted you can do that with resizepart command. It can be done in any other partitioner as well. That should resolve the issue properly.

Comment: @frostschutz yay, this did work! Thanks a lot. Feel free to properly post your fix as an answer, so I can accept it and you can be rich with internet points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @frostchutz I got this fixed by using `parted` to extend /dev/nvme0n1p3 by 2048 sectors.